# is there function like foreach from php in solidity?

Tags: foreach, solidity

this is so important, so when i made mapping

```
mapping(address => uint256) balances;
```

i cant check all address in the list like

```
foreach(balances as address => balance) log(address + ":" + balance + "\n");
```

so if i not store all address in sorted array i well not access any address in this array, so currently i use this:

```
  mapping(address => uint8) joiners;
  address[] members;
...
  if (joiners[_to] >= 1) {
    joiners[_to] = 1;
    members.push(_to);
  }
  balances[_to] += _value;
```

so then i can do this

```
uint allbalances = 0;
for(uint i; i < members.length; i++) {
allbalances = balances[members[i]];
}
return allbalances;
```

but this is disgusting, any one find another solution, or function like foreach from php??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this moment, You can not retrieve all the keys from the solidity `mapping`.

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html?highlight=mapping#mappings

I think that it is good to avoid loops in the contracts unless we know what we are doing. I could not get much on what you are trying to implement from your question. If your aim is to maintain the balances per address and also the total balances, I would do something similar as shown here.

```
contract Balance{

    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    uint public totalBalance;

    function credit() payable public{
        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        totalBalance += msg.value;
    }

    function debit(uint amount) public{
        //conditions
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= amount);

        //effects
        msg.sender.transfer(amount);
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        totalBalance -= amount;
    }

}
```

That is - Update totalBalance whenever you update the individual address balance.

---

Updating as per the question on the comments section:

If we need to iterate all the accounts, then we need to maintain the keys separately. My point was - total Balance would be called a lot more often than distributing profit to all accounts. So to avoid loops there for total balance calculation.

```
contract Ledger{

    address internal manager;
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    address[] public accounts;
    uint public totalBalance;

    constructor() public{
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function credit() payable public{
        if(balances[msg.sender] == 0){
            accounts.push(msg.sender);
        }

        balances[msg.sender] += msg.value;
        totalBalance += msg.value;
    }

    function debit(uint amount) public{
        //conditions
        require(balances[msg.sender] > amount);

        //effects
        msg.sender.transfer(amount);
        balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
        totalBalance -= amount;
    }

    function distributeProfit(uint amountToDistribute) public {
        require(manager == msg.sender);
        require(amountToDistribute > 0);

        //if profit might vary depends of balance, then place inside the loop.
        uint profit = amountToDistribute / accounts.length;

        for(uint index=0; index<accounts.length; index++){
            balances[accounts[index]] += profit;
        }
    }

 }
```

Comment: what if i went to distribute profits to all address have my token?
profit = 0.05;
foreach(balances as adrs => balance) adrs.transfer(balance / 10 ** uint256(decimals) * profit ether);
so how can i do it?

Comment: @AhmadOdeh, As I had mentioned, there is no way to get the list of keys from the mapping. As we maintain the `totalBalances` separately, if you want `keys`, you could maintain them separately. The point here is - where we place our loops!  I assume getting total balances would be called a lot more often than profit distribution. So, you could use the loop for this function. but avoid in the total balance calculation if possible.

Comment: what if user send all credit, and then someone send hem a new credit, so he get profit twice then i have better answer with use joiners array to check this, so you can avoid all bugs like this with function like foreach or with.. you know bug there its mean looses money.. a lot of money.. so its seem answer there is no think on solidity can do like foreach!!! are you sure? because i cant believe that Currency have 50 billion marketcap and dont have basic function like foreach!! so a well write a lot off code with a lot off gas make my app useless!!!

Comment: does the example code permits reentrancy hack?